# Is there a function in R that will keep rows in a table even when there are no values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a dataset of disease weeks where I'm trying to create a summary table that includes how many results came back positive for different diseases by disease weeks. The issue I'm running into is getting all weeks and diseases to show, even when there were 0 cases of a given disease in that week. So the code I'm using is:

```
DiseaseDataset %>%
  group_by(DiseaseWeek, Disease) %>%
  summarise(Total=n()) %>%
  mutate(Percent = (round(Total/sum(Total), digits = 2))*100)
```

The result is showing only disease weeks and diseases that have a value. I want every disease week and every disease to show, even if that value for that week is 0. I've tried adding .drop = FALSE, and I've also tried various functions in the padr package, but have not had any success. Any suggestions?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's hard to tell without a reproducible example of `DiseaseDataset`.  Would you mind including the output from `dput(DiseaseDataset)`?  That said, I suspect you could get your result by simply appending `%>% right_join(expand.grid(DiseaseWeek = unique(DiseaseDataset$DiseaseWeek), Disease = unique(DiseaseDataset$Disease)), by = c("DiseaseWeek", "Disease"))`, though you might have to fill in the blanks (`NA`s) afterward.

Comment: Ensure that the grouping vars are factors.  `.drop` is an argument in `count()` not `summarise()`.  Try: `DiseaseDataset  %>%  mutate(across(c(DiseaseWeek, Disease), factor)) %>%  count(DiseaseWeek, Disease, .drop = FALSE) `.

Comment: @27ϕ9 this worked, thank you so much!!! Thank you both for your time!